# Command to Combine text 100 lines at a time

Tags: 12.04, bash

I have a file with 7000 lines. I need to combine the lines 100 at a time to reduce it to 70 lines i.e

```
line 1
line 2
line 3
...
line 7000
```

becomes

```
line 1 line 2 line 3 line 4 ... line 100
line 101 line 102 line 103 line 104 ... line 200
...
line 6901 line 6902 line 6903 line 6904 ... line 7000
```

I know I can do this using code. Is there a way to do this on command line?

Comment: I assume you mean *"to reduce it to 70 files i.e"* instead of  *"to reduce it to 70 lines i.e"* :)

Comment: Ah, my eye catches the "I know I can do this using code" just now, is this not the type of answer you are looking for? Let me know and I'll remove it if so.

Comment: @JacobVlijm I was just commenting on your answer. Perhaps you could leave it as an example of how to do it via code.

Comment: Ah, I see, just undeleted it, please add the comment to the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try xargs:

```
xargs -L 100 < file
```

Test:

```
for i in {1..7000}; do echo "line $i"; done | xargs -L 100
```

Comment: Excellent. Just a heads up, my file contained quotes so `xargs -0 -L 100 -d "\n" < file` worked for me.

Comment: Yes, you can omit `echo`. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like this:

```
split -l 100 --numeric-suffixes--additional-suffix=.tmp The_Big_File fragment_  
for f in fragment_[0-9][0-9].tmp ; do  
    tr "\n" " " <$f  
    echo  
    rm $f
done
```

Comment: Interesting approach. I'll go with Cyrus' answer though.